# add more items it object during runtime.

Tags: swift

I have a object for restaurants that contain the name, rating and image name.  as you can see below. how can I add more restaurants to my list of restaurants?

```
    class Restaurant {
    var name : String = ""
    var rating : Float = 0
    var image : UIImage?
    init(name:String, rating: Float, imageName:String){
        self.name = name
        self.rating = rating
        self.image = UIImage(named:imageName)
    }
}

var restaurants: [Restaurant] = [
    Restaurant(name:"mikes", rating:5, imageName:"0"),
    Restaurant(name:"mexican", rating:8, imageName:"1"),
    Restaurant(name:"french",rating:3, imageName:"2"),
    Restaurant(name:"hippie",rating:9, imageName:"3"),
    Restaurant(name:"Greek", rating:0, imageName:"mold")
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
restaurants += Restaurant(name"Another", rating:10, imageName:"AwesomeImageName")
```